Error while deploying MERN stack application on Vercel
I'm trying to host a MERN stack application with the following folder structure:
root

backend

server.js (entry)
other files


frontend

build
node_modules
package.json
.gitignore
other files


node_modules (for backend)
.gitignore
package.json
vercel.json

My root package.json file:
{
  ...,
  "main": "backend/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3"
  }
}

Vercel.json:
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "amazone",
    "builds": [
      { "src": "backend/server.js", "use": "@vercel/node" },
      { "src": "frontend/package.json", "use": "@vercel/static-build", "config": { "distDir": "frontend/build" } }
    ],
    "routes": [
      { "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "backend/server.js" },
      { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "frontend/build/$1" }
    ]
  }
  

The error I'm receiving on the domain (https://amazonee.vercel.app/) is as follows:
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/frontend/build/index.html'"
}

Error in the logs:
Error: No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.
With the same configuration, I had hosted another MERN stack application before and it is working fine (https://spcommerce.vercel.app/). Please help me resolve this issue.

So, I figured out the solution by exporting the server.js file as module.exports = app and updating the vercel.json file as follows:
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "amazone",
    "builds": [
      { "src": "backend/server.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }
    ],
    "routes": [
      { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "backend/server.js" }
    ]
  }

